# Рекурсивная функция. Поиск путей файлов во множесте папок

Tags: python, файлы, рекурсия, ос

Хочу просканировать директорию с неопределённым количеством поддиректорий, и вывести список путей ко всем файлам.

```
import os
def path_cheker(dir):
    file_list=[]
    for item in os.listdir(dir):
        full_path=os.path.join(dir,item)
        if os.path.isdir(full_path):  #Если item это папка, захит и сканирует её
            path_cheker(full_path)
        elif os.path.isfile(full_path): 
            file_list.append(full_path)
    return file_list

task_dir="movie_analis\\task"
print(path_cheker(task_dir))
```

Выводит пустой список...:

```
[]
```

Подскажите пожалуйста, в чём ошибка с добавлением в список, голову сломал.

Из ответов: все рабочие,но моей логике больше всего [подошло](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1412633/496872) решение [crazyelf](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/260769/crazyelf)

Конечный код, такого вида:

```
import os
def path_cheker(papka, result_list=None):
    if result_list==None:
       result_list=[]
    for item in os.listdir(papka):
        full_path=os.path.join(papka,item)
        if os.path.isdir(full_path): 
            path_cheker(full_path)
        elif os.path.isfile(full_path): 
            result_list.append(full_path)
    return result_list

task_dir="movie_analis\\task"
path_cheker(task_dir)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Хоть ответ с выносом переменной из функции и работает, но так лучше не делать. По-нормальному все переменные должны передаваться в функции явным образом. В этой парадигме ваш код нужно было бы написать так:

```py
def path_cheker(dir, file_list=None):
    if file_list is None:
        file_list=[]
    for item in os.listdir(dir):
        full_path=os.path.join(dir,item)
        if os.path.isdir(full_path): 
            path_cheker(full_path, file_list)
        elif os.path.isfile(full_path): 
            file_list.append(full_path)
    return file_list
```

Обратите внимание, что нельзя использовать в питоне в качестве дефолтных параметров коллекции, например так `file_list=[]`. Почему - этот вопрос много раз тут обсуждался, я не буду повторяться. Ну то есть использовать конечно можно, но поведение функции будет не такое, как ожидается.

Кроме того, хорошо бы поменять название переменной `dir` на, скажем, `path`, потому что `dir` - это встроенная функция питона. Перекрывать встроенные функции нехорошо.

Comment: Спасибо.! Давило что из ответа Сергей Кох, функция ссылалась на список вне функции, но работало :-) Теперь работает и ничего  не давит :-)

Comment: @НикитаТимоходцев Ну да, в идеале функции должны быть как можно более автономными и прозрачными, тогда к ним и тесты писать легко и логику в них понять проще )

Answer (score 3):

Самый простой способ -

```
[str(file) for file in pathlib.Path(dir).rglobe('\*.*')) if file.is_file()]
```

`pathlib` намного удобнее для операций с файлами, входит в стандартные библиотеки питона

Comment: Спасибо большое за наводку. В будущем пригодится. Прохожу курсы по парсингу на питоне, сейчас изучаем библиотеку OS. Это домашнее задание, которе нужно решить без привлечния сторонних библиотек :-(

Comment: Библиотека pathlib такая же сторонняя, как и os, они обе являются стандартными для Питона и не требуют установки.

Странно, что на курсах дают устаревший подход :(

Comment: На курсах вообще мало что дают, до всего приходится доходить часами затыков и затупов. Т.к. я новичёк, хотя больше понимать а не знать, пока иду по пути "Лучше понимать но тупить в малом числе библиотек" чем "Вообе не понимать многих".

Answer (score 2):

У вас при каждом вызове функции список обнуляется  `file_list=[]`.
Вынесете создание списка из функции.

```
import os
file_list=[]
def path_cheker(dir):
```

Comment: Спасибо! действиетльно заработало :-)